# printing command name in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, command

```
#!/bin/bash

cmdname=${0##*/} 
tmplogfile="/tmp/."$cmdname".log"

echo $cmdname
exit 0
```

I have above shell script to do some task.
I am not understanding what `${0##*/}` means here. I changed `${0##*/}` to `${0}`, results are same. Could somebody tell me what the extra `##*/`
means?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations)

Comment: It is more or less equivalent to `cmdname=$(basename "$0")`; you can look up the `basename` command quite easily.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler After reading the following answer, I also got your point. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shell variable substitution notation for removing the largest prefix pattern matching the expresion after **##**. This expression is a shell pattern rather than a regular expression one. In this case, its removes the longest prefix from $0 ending in /. For example, for the script below:

```
/home/user/> cat /home/user/script
echo 'Value of $0      ' : $0
echo 'Value of ${0##*/}' : ${0##*/}

/home/user/> sh script
Value of $0       : script
Value of ${0##*/} : script

/home/user/> sh /home/user/script
Value of $0       : /home/user/script
Value of ${0##*/} : script
```

From [FreeBSD sh manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh):

> **${parameter##word}**
>
> ```
> Remove Largest Prefix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a
> pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in parameter, with
> the largest portion of the    prefix matched by the pattern deleted.
> ```

Although this is FreeBSD sh manpage, the same applies to all Bourne like shells around.